# I went to the phone settings, modified a permission, How to make the app restart, back to MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am doing a targetVersion upgrade in my app. Now I have a problem. When I go to phone settings, I manually refused permission. When I go back to my APP, I want to restart it and return to MainActivity. Now when I go back, it just restarts the current Activity. Can you give me some advice?

I checked some programs. They confirmed whether they were modified by judging `savedInstanceState != null`. I think this is wrong because I backed up the data in savedInstanceState and only judged `savedInstanceState != null` is not OK, it is one-sided.

Comment: Ask permission when you wanted to use that feature. don't redirect the user to MainActivity.

Comment: Ask all permission at the beginning. If the user does `deny` any permission. Ask only relevant permissions at a particular point.

Comment: @AshishKudale  If the user manually modifies the permissions I need, when the Activity restarts, the data I have previously manipulated, the data passed by the Intent, the data I store in the Application, will appear null, so I need to determine whether the user has to modify the permissions themselves. Under normal logic, I will apply for permission.

Comment: You have to recheck for permission in OnResume Method of your activity.

Comment: @TheAnkush What do you mean by saying that every time I go to record whether I got permission before OnPause, will I check the status of this permission when I am on OnResume? I feel like I can only do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store your data in more persistent matter (shared preferences, database, files, whatever applies) and manually restore it.

When user revokes permissions through settings app process gets killed without any callbacks to prevent unwanted behavior, for example:

1. Activity checks READ permission in `onCreate`
2. user pauses activity and revokes permission in settings
3. Activity resumes assuming it still owns permission and crashes on read attempt

This includes killing all ongoing services as well. Regular Activity lifecycle doesn't apply in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer，This helps me.I will think about how to implement it.

Comment: when I change the data in the mainActivity , it doesn't affect . I think it save the last state and not feeling with the changes in the new state . I have the sane case and I don't know what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Either you can check in OnResume if the permissions have changed. However this would hten be done whenver you just "tab out and tab back in*" to the application. A better way would be to check if savedInstanseState !=null and if so you recheck the relevant permissions, and if they have changed you finish() the activity to go back to MainActivity, and/or send an intent to restart the MainActivity if that is needed.

savedInstanceState can be "not null" in more cases than changing the permission as you pointed out, so you should recheck the relevat permissions to make sure that something actually changed.